# Is there a CryptKeeper-like app for OS X?

Tags: osx, encryption

CryptKeeper (Linux) creates an encrypted folder on a drive, then mounts it when you need it. Decrypting on the fly when click to view a file or drag one out of the mounted drive.

Is there a software that does the same thing on Mac OS X?

Retyping a password everytime you want to view an individual file really stinks, or have to wait to decrypt and entire directory just to view one file stinks also. I would love to hear that here is a port or a fork of cryptkeeper in OS X.

Comment: Regular encrypted .dmg no good?

Comment: DId not realize there existed such an animal.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/HT201599 You can make 'regular' or 'sparse', which will resize; save the password in keychain for auto-open, or not.

Comment: Yeah, what I was looking for was the encrypted sparse image. A guy has got to keep his porn collection away from prying eyes. Now that my kids are old enough to begin to use a computer, I don't want them to run into stuff by mistake through spotlight searches and stuff.

Comment: Ha ha ha - you can, btw, hide folders from Spotlight ... but I guess that would be a different question. Lemme throw some of that into an answer, just for the sake of completeness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Apple's own Encrypted Disk Image format, in fixed & variable sizes [grow/shrink to fit, sparseimage]

<del>Blatantly lifted</del> Borrowed from
[Apple KB: How to create a password-protected (encrypted) disk image](https://support.apple.com/HT201599)

The KB is actually out of date as of El Capitan & the new Disk Utility layout, but
**File > New Image > Blank Image** [or Image from Folder]
will do just the job, the New Image icon has gone.

> ## How to create a password-protected (encrypted) disk image
>
> Learn how to use Disk Utility to create an encrypted disk image.
>
> An encrypted disk image works just like a regular disk image but
>   requires a password to open and become available ("mount"). You can
>   move files to or from an encrypted disk image as easily as you can
>   from a non-encrypted disk image.  Follow these steps to create an
>   encrypted disk image:
>
> 1. Open Disk Utility (located in /Applications/Utilities/).
> 2. Click the New Image button, or choose **File > New > Blank Disk Image.**
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Type a name in the Save As field. This name will be used for the disk image (.dmg) file.
> 4. Change the save destination if you wish.
> 5. Select a size for the disk image file from the Size pop-up menu.
> 6. Choose a different volume format if you don't want to use the default Mac OS X Extended (Journaled).
> 7. Choose an image format. You can use "sparse disk image" for a disk image that only uses as much space as it needs, rather than a set
>      amount of space. If you're not sure, use "read/write disk image"
>      choice.
> 8. Choose 128-bit AES encryption (and/or 256-bit AES in Mac OS X v10.5 or later) from the Encryption pop-up menu to encrypt the image's
>      contents with a password. 1. If you don't choose an encryption, your
>      new image won't be encrypted.
> 9. Click the Create button.
> 10. Enter and verify a [good password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1506) in the dialog window that appears. This password will be saved in your keychain by default, or
>       you can deselect "Remember password (add to keychain)" if you don't
>       want it saved. You can store the password in the keychain for
>       convenience.
> 11. Click OK.
>
> **Important**: If you forget the password, data stored in the encrypted disk image cannot be retrieved. If you have saved the
>   password in the keychain, the password will be available to you there.